# Popup on AOD and Off Screen

Tags: android, popup, off-screen

I just port my notfifcation class to Oreo and got a question how do Whatsapp and over Apps show  a small popup on AOD or if the screen is completly off ? Because the popups look the same as I think I thought that this maybe a standrd thing, but did'nt found anything about this in the notificastion section of the developer doc. This is how looks like:[A snapshot of a Whatsapp Msg and below another Message from a Settings dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6KQ5.png)

Comment: And what's `AOD`?

Comment: Always On Display.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it. I must wake the screen before sending the notification, than it looks exactly like the snapshot's. If somebody is interested I can post the code.